# encountered unexpected token:<eof> jsqlparser postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, jsqlparser

When I passed this postgresql query in jsql parser it gave this error but when I run this in postgresql query console it work without any problem. whats the reason ?

**NOTE**:
this error also occurred when I worked with apache calcite.

Query:

`BEGIN;SELECT * FROM general.projects_bank;COMMIT;`

error:

```
net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.ParseException: Encountered unexpected token:<EOF>
    at line 1, column 49.

Was expecting one of:

"("
"ALTER"
"ANALYZE"
"BEGIN"
"CALL"
"COMMENT"
"COMMIT"
"CREATE"
"DECLARE"
"DELETE"
"DESCRIBE"
"DROP"
"END"
"EXEC"
"EXECUTE"
"EXPLAIN"
"GRANT"
"INSERT"
"MERGE"
"PURGE"
"RENAME"
"REPLACE"
"RESET"
"ROLLBACK"
"SAVEPOINT"
"SET"
"SHOW"
"TRUNCATE"
"UPDATE"
"UPSERT"
"USE"
"VALUE"
"VALUES"
"WITH"
<K_SELECT>
```

Comment: Yes, that is bad syntax. If you insist on writing multiple SQL statements in a single command, you have to separate them with semicolons. But the whole exercise is pointless, and you should omit the transaction commands.

Comment: Why it is bad syntax? While I run this in Postgresql query console, it executes successfully

Comment: No, it won't execute in the console. You forgot a semicolon.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I added the semicolon but it did not work

Comment: Now that will work in `psql` if the table exists and you gave permissions on it. It probably won't work with jsql. As I said, remove `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`, they are pointless.